# How to disable openapi docs API calls in Ambassador api gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, aws-api-gateway, ambassador

is there a way to stop Ambassador from polling services for open api docs?

I have tried disabling the developerportal mapping but still not working.

```
time="2020-06-11 04:59:49" level=error msg="Bad HTTP response" func=github.com/datawire/apro/cmd/amb-sidecar/devportal/server.HTTPGet.func1 file="github.com/datawire/apro@/cmd/amb-sidecar/devportal/server/fetcher.go:165" status_code=404 subsystem=fetcher url="https://127.0.0.1:8443/<nameofservice>/api/auth/info/.ambassador-internal/openapi-docs"
```

Kubernetes version : 1.16
AES version: 1.4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the doc polling in version 1.5.0+ by setting the environment variable POLL_EVERY_SECS to 0.